# How to track custom events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a form that has multiple drop-downs and a submit button. This form posts via ajax and returns a different result depending on the combination selected in the dropdowns. Assuming I get a desired result, I want to be able to track this combination in analytics.

I would have expected to be able to use a javascript snippet that would allow me to push the custom event, along with the custom parameters, when the ajax result has come back. However I'm finding it very difficult to understand how to do this.

I've taken a look at the GA4 / Tag Manager documentation and I can see how to create the event and parameters, but when it comes to triggers I'm not sure what to do? GA provides the option to create a button click trigger, but I don't want to capture this data when the button is clicked - I only want to capture it when the response is received from the server. Ideally I'd do something like this:

```
$.post('/my_endpoint',
    {
        dropdown1: dropdown1_value
        dropdown2: dropdown2_value,
        dropdown3: dropdown3_value,
        dropdown4: dropdown4_value
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        if(<my_condition>) {
            // Push to GA with dropdown1_value, dropdown2_value, dropdown3_value, dropdown4_value
        }
    });
```

Is there no way via script to push this event with the required parameters? You can see I require the ability to push the event manually, rather than relying on GA's triggers.

I recall in the past I've used `dataLayer.push()`, however this was years ago and analytics has evolved since I've last used it. I guess I'm trying to find Google Analytics APIs for pushing custom events, or does such a thing no longer exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `dataLayer.push()` of your parameters and an event like following:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'your-event-name', 'dropdown1_value' : value1, 'dropdown2_value' : value2, ...});
```

So in Google Tag Manager you have to create a dataLayer variable for how many values of dropdwon you want to pass. Then you have to create a GA4 Tag with the name you want, you enter the parameters with the values you retrieve from the dataLayer variables and as trigger you use an event named '*your-event-name*'.

Comment: Thank you, Michele. This gave me enough to work on. I found the following tutorial that helped expand on the above. Hopefully this will be of use to anyone else trying to understand custom events: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-custom-event-trigger/